# What aws storage service should be used for different types of data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Want to know which is the best aws storage service for different types of data.

Comment: This is very ambiguous and opinion based, please be specific about the exact problem and exact types of data.

Comment: Have a look at [8 types of AWS storage services explained](https://mitrai.com/tech-guide/eight-types-of-aws-storage-services-explained/).
It is very easy to get in touch first by using your favorite websearch. If you have a specific question (which data, how fast to access, how long to store, for which use case...) write this in your question and you will get a specific answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this intro session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6K0Sds9Y2N0) explaining the different databases depending on your data needs

If you are not thinking of a database but object/file storage, then you can find a service comparison at https://aws.amazon.com/products/storage/